# Choosing between multi-module and single-module design

Tags: architecture

What are the differences between multi-module and single-module software architectures? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each? When should each one be used, and why?

Comment: Please don't write answers in question bodies. Instead, move your answer into an answer. That way, people can vote on the quality of the question and and answer separately, and you can eventually accept the answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, for future. I am a new user.

Comment: Not a problem, I understand. Although you can make that edit now; you don't have to wait for next time. Or I could make it for you.

Comment: I think I need your help because
Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

Users with less than 100 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 7 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Thanks

Comment: Oh, right, that was a feature they put in to prevent people from using answers incorrectly. I can do it. Also, have an upvote and five "learning how to use the site" reputation points.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main advantage using multiple modules is that you can re-use them, whereas single modules often contain multiple functionalities, not necesarilly related to each other, and are impractical for reuse. This depends on the size of the project, but for large projects multiple modules bring more advantages.

Multiple modules also provide an easier to update and change system. If you find a bug, you'd only need to update the module containing the bug, not the whole system.

Compile time is also better for a system with more modules as not necesarilly all of them need to be compiled for small changes (of course, with a smart enough compiler this shouldn't be a problem for single-module programs either).

Testing is another issue - testing smaller modules can decrease the number of bugs as they can be pinpointed to their specific module.

As for disadvantages, multiple modules can be harder to maintain; if they exist in a large number and aren't documented well enough, following dependencies can also be a tedious task.

Again, this depends on the size of the project.

Answer (score 1):

*Note: this answer was originally posted by the OP as a self-answer in the question body due to the eight-hour self-answer restriction for new users.*

From http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/project.html:

> Depending on the logical and functional requirements to the project, you can create a single-module or a multi-module project.
>
> - A single-module project is most suitable for developing simple applications.
> - A multi-module project is used for complex tasks:
>
>   - Creating a complicated logical structure.
>   - Providing separate output for the various parts of the project, for example, deploying multiple JAR files.
>   - Providing different SDKs for the various parts of the project.
>
> Multi-module projects give you important advantages. Breaking your project into a number of independent modules, you can:
>
> - Reuse and share modules between projects, which can be useful for the collections of utility classes.
> - Build and test modules separately.
> - Keep each module under its own version control.
>
> Project structure is initially defined on project creation, and can be modified. For example, you can create a single-module project and later add more modules.